# I used axios in the nodejs environment to send a picture to the nestjs server, but the server did not get the picture information

Tags: node.js, axios, nestjs

I use streaming to send images to the server instead of sending the entire image  https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

```
(async () => {
  let r = await axios
    .post(`http://localhost:5000/upload`, {
      file: fs.createReadStream("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Pictures\\a.jpg"),

      // Error: Request failed with status code 500
      // file: await fs.readFile("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Pictures\\a.jpg")
    })
    .then(v => v.data);
  l(r); // ok
})();
```

Server code https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload

```
  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  upload(@UploadedFile() file, @Body() body) {
    l(file); // undefined
    return 'ok';
  }
```

I have tried it for a long time, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> yarn add form-data

```
(async () => {
  const l = console.log;
  const axios = require("axios");
  const fs = require("fs-extra");
  var FormData = require("form-data");
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append("file", fs.createReadStream("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Pictures\\a.jpg"));
  form.append("type", "avatar");

  let r = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/upload",
    data: form,
    headers: form.getHeaders()
  }).then(v => v.data);
  l(r); // ok
})();
```